# Add time to all date/time values inside an array

Tags: php

I have a table that has a column of timestamped values (YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS) titled "date_pulled". I want to add 5 days to all those values and store it in an array. I tried the below, but it doesn't seem to work. Not sure if I can use `date_add` in this fashion/if there's another way to do this?

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $future[] = date_add($row["date_pulled"], date_interval_create_from_date_string("5 days"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $future[] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+5 days', strtotime($row['date_pulled'])));
}
```

See I also removed the obsolete condition around it.

Answer (score 0):

The database can perfectly do that already:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(date_pulled, INTERVAL 5 DAY) AS date_plus5 FROM ...
```